# AppFabric "Cache referred to does not exist"

Tags: c#, caching, appfabric

Getting the following error while trying to access an AppFabric cache. Our Cache was created yesterday and nothing happened, that we know of, to remove the Cache. Does anybody have any suggestions on troubleshooting what could be causing our Cache to be removed from the server?

I was able to resolve the error by simply running `New-Cache EAI` at the PowerShell command prompt

**ErrorCode:SubStatus:Cache referred to does not exist. Contact administrator or use the Cache administration tool to create a Cache.**

```
var cache = new DataCacheFactory().GetCache("EAI");
```

FYI: We are using SQL for our config store

Comment: If you're using XML config, is it possible the file was overwritten?

Comment: thanks, I just added a note that we're using SQL for our config store.

Comment: Any chance that someone re-ran the initialisation then? It's certainly not the most intuitive procedure..